# Android Cannot read raw response body of a converted body

Tags: android, exception, retrofit, retrofit2, httpresponse

In the below code Im syncing my data to the server but the app keeps crashing with this  message Exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body. I am unable to fix it. What is causing the crash and what is the solution?

```
private void uploadToServer(String date, String userid, JSONArray attachment, String expense, String ad_user, String ad_pass, String versionCode, String apiVersion, String dcrSync, String urlParameters) {
   RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), attachment.toString());
APIinterface apIinterface = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(getApplicationContext()).create(APIinterface.class);
    final Call<ResponseBody> call = apIinterface.uploadExpenseData(Datafields.tag_url.get("expense_sync").toString(), date, userid, attachment.toString(), expense, ad_user, ad_pass, versionCode, apiVersion, dcrSync);
Log.e("attachement", attachment.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.e("syncObjetc", String.valueOf(response));
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                String url = response.raw().request().url().toString();
                ResponseBody body = response.raw().body();
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(Sync.this, responseBody.string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(Sync.this, body.string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONObject messageObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");
                    JSONObject codeObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("code");
                    JSONObject syncObjetc = jsonObject.getJSONObject("synchData");
                    String message = messageObj.getString("message");
                    int code = codeObject.getInt("code");
                    String date = syncObjetc.getString("date");
                    Log.e("String message ", message);
                    Log.e("syncObjetc", String.valueOf(syncObjetc));
                    Log.e("resbody ", responseBody.string());

                    altDialog.setMessage(message);
                    altDialog.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Sync.this, Sync.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        }
                    });
                    altDialog.show();
                    if (code == 0) {
                        syncExpense(date);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Sync.this, "Sync Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Faliure", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the logcat:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody.source(OkHttpCall.java:274)
        at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:173)
        at com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo.Sync$19.onResponse(Sync.java:1898)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.459 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.
2023-04-24 12:58:48.459 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody.source(OkHttpCall.java:274)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.459 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:173)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.459 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo.Sync$19.onResponse(Sync.java:1898)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.459 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
2023-04-24 12:58:48.460 9893-9893/com.anantfso.glenmark_fso_demo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: please post whole stacktrace

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski - I have added the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to read `ResponseBody` multiple times and that's not allowed. as you can do this only once, so When you call `responseBody.string()` and `body.string()`, you read the response body twice, and the second one is causing the `IllegalStateException`. If you need to access it more time then you must do a copy first and then access that copy instead of original response.

Comment: Ur solution is correct but can u help me understand why the app started crashing suddenly where as it was working fine previously